# how to handler a SqlExceptionHelper in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, error-handling

I have a project in spring boot and I need to send an alarm through email when the database fell down. I have the configuracion in the "application.properties" down "spring.datasource.url" etc.

To know what error i have to handler I cut the conection to the database before enter to this line code:

```
entityNameRepo.save(entityName);
```

And I get this error:

```
2021-09-23 12:48:37.962  WARN 25992 --- [   scheduling-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase
    : HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@58f2466c (Conexión cerrada). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
2021-09-23 12:48:37.963  WARN 25992 --- [   scheduling-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@10157555 (Conexión cerrada). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
2021-09-23 12:48:37.964  WARN 25992 --- [   scheduling-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@23c64838 (Conexión cerrada). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
2021-09-23 12:48:37.965  WARN 25992 --- [   scheduling-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@52d50775 (Conexión cerrada). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
2021-09-23 12:48:37.965  WARN 25992 --- [   scheduling-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@6e3e13d1 (Conexión cerrada). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
2021-09-23 12:48:37.967  WARN 25992 --- [   scheduling-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@3649ec86 (Conexión cerrada). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
2021-09-23 12:48:37.968  WARN 25992 --- [   scheduling-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@703cbbbc (Conexión cerrada). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
2021-09-23 12:48:37.968  WARN 25992 --- [   scheduling-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@3acca588 (Conexión cerrada). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
2021-09-23 12:48:37.969  WARN 25992 --- [   scheduling-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@beafa91 (Conexión cerrada). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
2021-09-23 12:48:37.970  WARN 25992 --- [   scheduling-1] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-1 - Failed to validate connection oracle.jdbc.driver.T4CConnection@3b39de45 (Conexión cerrada). Possibly consider using a shorter maxLifetime value.
2021-09-23 12:49:07.964  WARN 25992 --- [   scheduling-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 08006
2021-09-23 12:49:07.965 ERROR 25992 --- [   scheduling-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : HikariPool-1 - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30003ms.
2021-09-23 12:49:07.965  WARN 25992 --- [   scheduling-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 17002, SQLState: 08006
2021-09-23 12:49:07.965 ERROR 25992 --- [   scheduling-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Error de E/S: The Network Adapter could not establish the connection (CONNECTION_ID=NURi78MT40q3/iIJhcdfOA==)
2021-09-23 12:49:07.979 ERROR 25992 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.s.s.TaskUtils$LoggingErrorHandler    : Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task

org.springframework.dao.DataAccessResourceFailureException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.JDBCConnectionException: Unable to acquire JDBC Connection
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:255) ~[spring-orm-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233) ~[spring-orm-5.3.8.jar:5.3.8]
```

Do you know how to catch this error?

I tried handler it with creating a class like:
public class WarningHandlerImpl implements SqlExceptionHelper.WarningHandler{
but i counld´t.

thanks!

Comment: Try following this guide:https://www.javaguides.net/2018/10/jdbc-handling-sqlexceptions.html.